# Twitter mining issue with the rate limit

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, mining

I have been working in a reseach project involving getting friends and followers info from twitter . I have written a code that works fine for sample account like mine who has 1k followers or friends . But I am having trouble running it for Donald Trump account who has 12.2 Million followers . In my program after querying for some time rate limit is exceeded and I wait for 15 mins and then again request for the same .  This process works fine for around 1 Million users info but it gets stuck after that or sometimes it gives URL error . Please suggest what could be the issue when dealing with such large data and what would be the solution . Please find code snippet for the same below  -

```
def get_info_by_screen_name(t, screen_names):

    sn_to_info = {}
    while len(screen_names) > 0:

        # Process 100 ids at a time...

        screen_names_str = ','.join([str(sn) for sn in screen_names[:100]])
        screen_names = screen_names[100:]

        response = make_twitter_request(t,
                                        getattr(getattr(t, "users"), "lookup"),
                                        screen_name=screen_names_str)

        if response is None:
            break

        if type(response) is dict:  # Handle Twitter API quirk
            response = [response]

        for user_info in response:
            sn_to_info[user_info['screen_name']] = user_info

    return sn_to_info


    t = oauth_login()

    friends_ids, followers_ids = get_friends_followers_ids(t,
                                                           screen_name="realDonaldTrump",
                                                           friends_limit=100,
                                                           followers_limit=100)

    # Basic usage...


    print friends_ids
    print followers_ids
    # Basic usage...
    info = {}
    data_test = {}
    info.update(get_info_by_id(t, friends_ids))
```

Comment: cant see your code snippet.

Comment: @vatsalmevada pfa

Comment: You should not wait to hit the rate before stopping. Have you tried to go to sleep for 16 minutes just before hitting the rate limit (which is set at 180 requests per 15 minutes)?

Comment: @Efferalgan thanks for your reply . Now that issue is resolved  . I am getting Memory error in my below code - 

        ids_str = ','.join([str(_id) for _id in ids[:100]])
        ids = ids[100:] <--------- this point has memory error .

where ids dict has around 12.5 Million entries . what could be the issue here could you please suggest.

Comment: The problem you have here, is that, obviously, 12.5 million entries is too big for your memory. I don't know what you are trying to do with your data, but if possible, you should process the ids as you get them, or by chunks of 100 000 or whatever size of chunk fits better.